# Segmentation fault (core dumped) c++ linux terminal windows 10

Tags: c++, operating-system, job-scheduling

I am trying to do Shortest Job First Scheduling(batch, non preemptive) reading input from `input.txt` file but it throws `segmentation fault(core duped)` here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *dir;
    char string[100];
    int pId, arrival, cpuBurst, priority, i, j, t, nJobs;
    int pid[30], pt[30], burstTime[30], arrTime[30], waitTime[30], turnAroundTime[30], comp[30];
    float avgWaitTime = 0, avgTurnAroundTime = 0, resTime = 0, time = 0, throughput = 0;
    int countValue[7], responseTime[30];

    dir = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    fgets(string, 100, dir);
    j = 0;
    while (fscanf(dir, "%d %d %d %d", &pId, &arrival, &cpuBurst, &priority) != EOF)
    {
        arrTime[j] = arrival;
        pid[j] = pId;
        burstTime[j] = cpuBurst;
        pt[j] = priority;
        j += 1;
    }

    nJobs = j;
    for (i = 0; i < nJobs; i++)
    {
        for (j = i; j < nJobs; j++)
        {
            if (arrTime[i] > arrTime[j])
            {
                t = arrTime[i];
                arrTime[i] = arrTime[j];
                arrTime[j] = t;

                t = burstTime[i];
                burstTime[i] = burstTime[j];
                burstTime[j] = t;
                t = pid[j];
                pid[j] = pid[i];
                pid[i] = t;
            }
        }
    }
    comp[0] = arrTime[0] + burstTime[0];
    int numCount = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nJobs; i++)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (j = i + 1; j < nJobs; j++)
        {
            if (comp[i] > arrTime[j])
            {
                countValue[count] = j;
                count++;
            }
        }
        for (int a = 0; a < nJobs; a++)
        {
            int resVal = countValue[a];
            int resValSec = countValue[a + 1];

            if (resVal != 0 && resValSec != 0)
            {
                if (burstTime[resVal] > burstTime[resValSec])
                {
                    t = arrTime[resVal];
                    arrTime[resVal] = arrTime[resValSec];
                    arrTime[resValSec] = t;

                    t = burstTime[resVal];
                    burstTime[resVal] = burstTime[resValSec];
                    burstTime[resValSec] = t;

                    t = pid[resValSec];
                    pid[resValSec] = pid[resVal];
                    pid[resVal] = t;
                }
                comp[numCount + 1] = comp[numCount] + burstTime[numCount + 1];
                ++numCount;
            }
        }
        turnAroundTime[i] = comp[i] - arrTime[i];
        avgTurnAroundTime = avgTurnAroundTime + turnAroundTime[i];
        waitTime[i] = turnAroundTime[i] - burstTime[i];
        avgWaitTime = avgWaitTime + waitTime[i];
        resTime = avgWaitTime;
    }
    printf("Process \t arrival \t completion");
    for (i = 0; i < nJobs; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d\t\t%d\t\t%d", pid[i], arrTime[i], comp[i]);
    }

    avgTurnAroundTime = avgTurnAroundTime / nJobs;
    resTime = resTime / nJobs;
    time = (resTime / avgTurnAroundTime);
    throughput = time / nJobs;

    printf("\nRun Stats");
    printf("\nThroughput=%.2f\n", throughput);
    printf("Average Response Time=%.2f\n", resTime);
    printf("Average Turn Around Time=%.2f\n", avgTurnAroundTime);
}
```

The input.txt file contains:

```
PID     ARRIVAL BURST   PRIORITY
100     0       10      1
101     6       10      1
102     8       4       1
103     12      20      1
104     19      15      1
105     30      5       1
106     35      10      1
```

Comment: have you tried debugging? Have you checked that `fopen` succeeds?

Comment: Q: What debugger are you using? [Gdb](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gdb-command-in-linux-with-examples/)?  Q: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?  Q: Did you get a stack traceback - particularly the line# - from the debugger?

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes, I tried and fopen succeeds.

Comment: Your debugger will show you that `resValSec` has an absurd value.  I think you're reading it from an element of `burstTime` that you never initialized.

Comment: @NateEldredge I have Initilized `burstTime[30]` at the top.

Comment: No you've defined it, its not initialised

Comment: Oh sorry, `resValSec` is read from `countValue`, not from `burstTime`.

Comment: @AlanBirtles you mean i need to initialized `burstTime` with `resValSec`?

Comment: Yeah, stepping through, on the `i == 0` iteration of the loop at line 41, the `j` loop at line 43 only initializes `countValue[0]` and `countValue[1]`.  So when `a == 1` on the loop below, `resValSec` is loaded from `countValue[2]` which contains garbage.  Remember that local arrays in C do not get initialized by default.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm getting same error

Comment: Then please edit your question to show what you changed and what happens now.  And since you said you tried debugging, you could include information about which line causes the segfault and what are the values of the relevant variables at that point (which your debugger can tell you).